# 'ST_SEGMENTIZE' function in PostGIS gives single output

Tags: postgis

I try to split a line into 2m segments but somehow the function `ST_SEGMENTIZE` returns the whole line assigning just one id.

An example:

```
CREATE TABLE line(name char(10), geom geometry);


INSERT INTO line VALUES('line','SRID=32637;LINESTRING(1 1, 1 3, 2 3, 3 3, 3 2, 4 2, 5 3)');


SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id, ST_AsText(ST_SEGMENTIZE(geom, 2)) AS geom FROM line;
```

Output:

```
id  geom
1   LINESTRING(1 1,1 3,2 3,3 3,3 2,4 2,5 3)
```

How can I achieve to get 2m segments from my line-input using PostGIS 2.5.1?

Answer (score 1):

[`ST_Segmentize`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Segmentize.html) will not split the input, it will add vertices to the original geometry so that the distance between vertices is the specified distance.

You may be looking for [`ST_LineSubstring`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineSubstring.html) instead, like in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285278/st-linesubstring-query-not-giving-expected-results/285280#285280)